# A closed even walk $W$ need not contain a Cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

While going through Graph theory by West ,I learnt that

> A closed odd walk $W$ contains an odd cycle.

Proved as

- If $W$ does not contain any repeated vertex ,it is as simple as to state the Theorem.
- In case of a repeated vertex $v$,Break walk into two part both Walk $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ starts with $v$ where $W_{1}$,$W_{2}$ $\varepsilon $  $W$
  Now as it is closed **odd**  walk ,we have combination possible

  **odd**=$\text{even+odd}$

so $W$ must contain an odd Walk having non repeated vertex ,thus it contains odd cycle.

Now My point is that can't we apply the same logic for even closed walk

i.e

**even**=$\text{even+even}$

**even**=$\text{odd+odd}$

Then why he is saying that there may not be aycle in closed even walk.

can anyone give counter graph??

can anyone correct me where i am wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

Consider the graph $K_2$. A closed walk is necessarily even in length here. However, there is clearly no cycle here.