# Why does a closed even walk not need to have a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading this in West's Graph Theory and I can't see why. It says because there can be repeats, but I don't know he means there. Can someone prove why closed even walks need not have a cycle? If there's a counter example proof, is that the only counter example? Like $K_2$ for example.

The other question doesn't answer whether $K_2$ is the only counter example. It doesn't have a proof of the whole statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A closed even walk $W$ need not contain a Cycle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076268/a-closed-even-walk-w-need-not-contain-a-cycle)

Comment: Consider traveling along a path, and then back along the same path in reverse.

Comment: That wouldn't be closed though, or am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk down a path and reverse the same path to end up at the same point you started, and hence close the walk.

**Update**: For another example, consider a star graph. Start from a leaf, go to the center go to another leaf, go to the center, repeat for as many leaves as you want, and then go back the original leaf.

Comment: How does reversing the path make the walk closed? I see why the walk is even but not why it's closed. I can see why an even walk need not contain a cycle but why doesn't a closed even walk need to contain a cycle?

Comment: A walk is closed if it ends at the starting point

Comment: I see now, I forgot that the endpoints would be the same after you reverse. Thanks!

Comment: Are walks where you reverse paths the only examples of this statement?

Comment: No, you can walk down a path, walk in reverse half way, then walk another path, reverse it to come back to the halfway of the first path and walk back to the starting point.

Comment: Got it. So is $a, b, c, d, e, d, c, f, g, f, c, b, a$ a closed even walk?

Comment: Yes, you got it.